# Is there a way to upgrade nodejs version via npm in Windows environment?

Tags: windows, node.js, npm

I'm trying to update nodejs in Windows environment via npm. Unfortunately the [module `n`](https://github.com/visionmedia/n) has [no support for Windows](https://github.com/visionmedia/n/issues/146).

In this case, it is possible to do it in another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't try to install/update node from npm. From the [FAQ](https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html) itself :

> #### How do I install node with npm?
>
> You don't. Try one of these node version managers:
>
> Unix:
>
> - http://github.com/isaacs/nave
> - http://github.com/visionmedia/n
> - http://github.com/creationix/nvm
>
> Windows:
>
> - http://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist
> - https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw

Comment: https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw does not seem to work with newer version of node (4.0+). The distribution repertory has changed its layout. Error message is `Download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node.exe, and save it as C:\Archivos de programa\nvmw\.nvmw\v4.2.1\node.exe`

Comment: However, I followed instructions in this issue : https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw/issues/58, and that seemed to solve the issue for those higher versions